# Bash bc returns (standard_in) 1: parse error only when part of for loop

Tags: bash, shell, bc, herestring

I'm iterating through an array of integers `${startTimes}` (marker locations in an audio file, in samples) and using `bc` to convert those integers to milliseconds. I'm passing the results into a new array `${msValuesArray}`. If I run each array element one at a time it works fine. If I run it in a `for` loop:

```
for i in $(seq 0 ${#startTimes[@]}); do 
    msValuesArray+=($(bc <<< ${startTimes[i]}/44.1))
done
```

The resulting `${msValuesArray}` contains the expected results, but the terminal outputs `(standard_in) 1: parse error`.

While I intend to use this in a shell script, and after reading other questions here I learned that adding `#!/bin/bash` to the beginning of the command avoids the parse error, I still don't understand the following:

a) why does the manual passing of a `${startTimes}` element into `bc` work without the parse error while the `for` loop also works, yet outputs the parse error (outside of the shell script)?

b) despite the parse error, I have the resulting array that I want. Should I ignore the error?

c) when adding `#!/bin/bash` to the beginning of the commands (still outside of the shell script, just in the command line) why are the results inaccessible? (Entering `echo ${msValuesArray[@]}` returns an empty array.)

d) While running inside the shell script, is the same error happening but just not printing to the terminal?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does the `starts` array look like? Does it have the same number of elements as `startTimes`? Is this your whole script? How do you run it? What do you mean by "adding `#!/bin/bash` in the command line"?

Comment: Sorry, bad copy/paste. I just fixed it. It's supposed to be `startTimes`. I don't have the whole script yet, just testing out commands one at a time in the command line to make sure my script will run (if there's a better method I'm all ears). For the shebang, if I enter all of this `#!/bin/bash; for...(etc)...; done` in the command line I get no parse error -- but also no accessible results. I'm assuming it's running in another shell that I can't access? Still learning, obviously.

Comment: And if it helps, `startTimes` looks like this: `0 87053 91463 190062 194472 290520 294930 387582 391992`. Just a bunch of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the array directly instead of going via indices:

```
for t in "${startTimes[@]}"; do
    msValuesArray+=($(bc <<< "$t / 44.1"))
done
```

This makes the loop easier to read.

You get a parse error because you're trying to access a non-existing element (see John1024's answer), so `bc` sees just `/ 44.1`. You shouldn't ignore the error.

You should quote your here-string, even though in this very instance it doesn't seem to cause problems<sup>1</sup>.

If you enter `#!/bin/bash` just on the command line, it has no effect at all, it's just considered a comment. It only does something as the first line of a script, namely indicate what interpreter should be used. If, as indicated by your comment, you enter the whole thing on a single line as

```
#!/bin/bash; for ... (etc) ...
```

nothing at all happens. It's just a comment.

Lastly, you're truncating your results. If you want them more precise, you can set `scale` to a sensible value, as in

```
bc <<< "scale = 3; $t / 44.1"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Problems such as (unwanted) word splitting and globbing. [This article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) is a good overview about the how and why of quoting.

Comment: Thanks very much! Can you elaborate on the importance of quotes for the here-string? I'm still fuzzy on quote usage, in general.

Comment: @Urphänomen I've added a link to a good article about quoting. The rule of thumb is really "if in doubt, quote".

Comment: Excellent, thank you @Benjamin W. An overview is just what I need, much appreciated.

Comment: @Urphänomen Benjamin's solution of `for t in "${startTimes[@]}"` appears to me to be a good one.  I recommend that you accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have an off-by-1 problem.  Observe that, with your sample startTimes, `seq` generates 10 numbers:

```
$ startTimes=(0 87053 91463 190062 194472 290520 294930 387582 391992)
$ seq 0 ${#startTimes[@]}
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The problem is that startTimes has only 9 entries:

```
$ declare -p startTimes
declare -a startTimes=([0]="0" [1]="87053" [2]="91463" [3]="190062" [4]="194472" [5]="290520" [6]="294930" [7]="387582" [8]="391992")
```

When `i=9`, startTimes[9] evaluates to an empty string and that leads to the `bc` error that you see:

```
$ i=9; msValuesArray+=($(bc <<< ${startTimes[i]}/44.1))
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Or, more directly:

```
$ bc <<<"/44.1"
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.